# Function return only first output value by default

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Suppose I have a function:

```
def my_func():
    return 1,2
```

What I want: If I call function like this:

```
a = my_func()
```

I want it to return **only the first output parameter**, i.e. `1`;
and if I call `a,b = my_func()` it returns **both** - `a=1` and `b=2`.

---

This task is about backward compatibility: I already have a lot of scripts when I use just `a = my_func()`, and now I want to add extra functionality. But now `a` is actually a tuple, consisting of both values: `(1,2)`

**Is it possible?**

Comment: To rephrase your question: do you want to alter the return value of your code, depending on how the result is unpacked? Or are you ok with altering all the other parts of your code?

Comment: @Carcigenicate https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/be4be158-3e9b-4e43-b3d8-afca34750080

Comment: I don't think this can be done: the function can't inspect how its results are unpacked (or not unpacked) on the calling line.

Comment: which python version? cannot reproduce either. Returning a tuple assigns `a` to a `tuple`. [mcve] please

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I thought you were saying that it was only returning the first element of the tuple. On a second read though, it seems that that's the desired behavior, not what's already happening.

Comment: Maybe add a parameter to the function, to indicate if it needs to use the new structure or not

Comment: How to distinguish whether `a` is supposed to be an `int` or a `tuple`?

Comment: People appear to misunderstand the question: the OP (likely) wants to change the function to be compatible with old and new code, but *not* change the calling lines.

Comment: @Evert you are right! That is what I want!

Comment: For any number of results other than one you could make the function a generator with multiple `yield` statements, but then, still, `a = my_func()` will become the generator itself, not the first result.

Comment: I'd suggest renaming the function (just slightly), and over time, update the legacy code. After all, the function's return signature has now changed, and it's therefore essentially a different function. Using the same name with a different return signature is confusing. And using different return types (single value vs tuple) depending on a kwarg, also feels like a bad pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a parameter with default value and you only need to add it in the new version executions.

[Pyfiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/e753b38c-2585-4807-9751-17d9096806cd)

```
def my_func(new_version=False):    
    return (1, 2) if new_version else 1

a = my_func()                 # backwards compatible
print("should be 1", a)
a = my_func(new_version=True) # new version available
print("should be (1, 2)", a)
```

Comment: This still requires changing the legacy code manually. In that case, it'd probably be better to use `a, b = my_func(...`.

Comment: backward compatibility is checked in the `a = my_func() # backwards compatible` line

Comment: besides it's the same answer as the other answer

Comment: So, in what way exactly is `a = my_func(new_version=True)` superior to `a = my_func()[0]`?

Comment: @tobias_k As OP requested it should be backwards compatible , so `my_func()` should still return the old `1` value

Comment: Jean-François Fabre, this version is really backwards compatible, the other answer will break old `my_func()` calls.

Comment: Ah, okay, I thought the version with two results was the "default" and the one with one the special case. Then it makes sense. Still, I think having a second function would be much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *output parameter*. The function returns a `tuple`.

If you want to change the actual return, value, this can only be done by providing a separate parameter:

```
def my_func(first_only=False):    
    return 1 if first_only else 1, 2
```

and provide it accordingly:

```
a = my_func(first_only=True)
```

Comment: No, you would get a `ValueError: too many values to unpack `. And OP would like to leave the legacy code unchanged.

Comment: Maybe he means `a,_` ?

Comment: `a, = 1,2,3` doesn't work though; why would it work with functions?

Comment: Or `a, *_ = my_func()`.